# Bizarre errors. Woman dressed from head to toe is NSFW... Picnic table and silly commands activate Json triggers

Tags: json

I'm using colab to execute basic prompts that are not offensive. If I use the new version in quality, it triggers saying that a woman holding a bag violates the rules! Picnic table with tablecloth is NSFW! It is not a valid Json. If I'm running via virtual server, since the new version doesn't like the drive I use on my PC, it's not my mistake! It happened three times today and the screen has already frozen. If it were run in a physical environment (my PC), I would know what would have done this, but, as it is a T4 GPU virtual environment, it changes all the time, it bugs all the time, it gets complicated! Does not trigger with negative prompt! It has occurred to me in past versions without adding this. I hope to have answers, as enriching the content is valid, but if this has become Haiper where a smile is NSFW, walking on the street means NSFW... Seaart, uniform of any kind, even a real nun (not NSFW) It's labeled NSFW, it's difficult to help. Another suggestion! Add a PayPal option. I want more credits, but only accepting Visa and Mastercard, whether in Brazil or worldwide, limits the platform's radius. I can't subscribe to a plan above, as it doesn't accept my card brand!

I tried to avoid the error by loading the page again, deleting the cell, everything... they have been happening a lot after midnight. If I use it in the afternoon, it doesn't happen. Do you understand gravity? Could it be a duplicate protocol error or are they running a fake version?